# Ping fails in Mininet, RYU - OpenFlow 1.3

Tags: mininet, openflow, ryu

I am using Mininet, RYU controller and OpenFlow 1.3, to create a topology where host `h1` is connected to host `h2` using a switch `p0es0` in the following way:

```
h1 h1-eth0:p0es0-eth3
h2 h2-eth0:p0es0-eth4
```

In my Ryu Controller application, I have the following code snippet to install rules on my `p0es0` switch to be able to reach h1 from h2 and vice-versa:

```
    # Install rule to forward packets destined to "10.0.0.2" (h2) via port 3
    ofproto = sw.ofproto        
    match = sw.ofproto_parser.OFPMatch( eth_type = 0x0800, ipv4_dst="10.0.0.1")
    action = sw.ofproto_parser.OFPActionOutput(4)
    inst = [sw.ofproto_parser.OFPInstructionActions(sw.ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS, [action])]
    mod = sw.ofproto_parser.OFPFlowMod(datapath=sw, match=match,
           instructions=inst, cookie=0, command=ofproto.OFPFC_ADD, idle_timeout=0, 
           hard_timeout=0, priority=100, flags=ofproto.OFPFF_SEND_FLOW_REM)
    sw.send_msg(mod)


    # Install rule to forward packets destined to "10.0.0.1" (h1) via port 4
    match = sw.ofproto_parser.OFPMatch( eth_type = 0x0800, ipv4_dst="10.0.0.1")
    action = sw.ofproto_parser.OFPActionOutput(4)
    inst = [sw.ofproto_parser.OFPInstructionActions(sw.ofproto.OFPIT_APPLY_ACTIONS, [action])]
    mod = sw.ofproto_parser.OFPFlowMod(datapath=sw, match=match,
           instructions=inst, cookie=0, command=ofproto.OFPFC_ADD, idle_timeout=0, 
           hard_timeout=0, priority=100, flags=ofproto.OFPFF_SEND_FLOW_REM)
    sw.send_msg(mod)
```

My dump-flow command confirms the correct installation of rules in the switch as expected:

*** p0es0 -----------------------------------------------------------------

OFPST_FLOW reply (OF1.3) (xid=0x2):

cookie=0x0, duration=1103.417s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, send_flow_rem priority=100,ip,**nw_dst=10.0.0.2 actions=output:4**

cookie=0x0, duration=1103.414s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, send_flow_rem priority=100,ip,**nw_dst=10.0.0.1 actions=output:3**

---

However, when I attempt to ping `h2` from `h1` or vice-versa, I get Destination Host Unreachable error. I tried using tcpdump on `p0es0-eth3` -- I see only ARP Request packets.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running Mininet without the arp flag. Adding the arp option fixed my problem.

i.e., sudo mn **--arp** --custom fTreeTopo.py --topo ftreetopo --controller=remote,ip=127.0.0.1